# What is the most simple and/or efficient way to check if variable value is base10 integer?

Tags: php, function, validation, variables, integer

I've been trying to think of a function that could be used to check a variable value if it is an integer in base10, regardless of is it type of integer or string. It would be used mostly for checking POST values, primarily produced by AJAX (which can be *easily* modified by user).

Googling does not produce relative results (for me), or I don't know the "correct" phrases to search with.

Problem with current built-ins is, that they all require extra-checking, as they "leak" *somehow*, when only allowed is base10 integers. For example, `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` passes "123 " (notice space at the end).

I've myself come up with two functions, which I'm also asking your opinion for, what you think of them. Are they as reliable as I think they are? Which one of them I should use, or do you know something better?

```
function myIsInt1($value)
{
    if(is_int($value))return true;
    if(is_float($value))return ($value===(float)(int)$value);
    if(!is_string($value))return false;
    return ($value===(string)(int)$value);
}
```

and

```
function myIsInt2($value)
{
    /* this wont work as supposed to, because it allows overflowing integers */
    if(is_int($value))return true;
    if(is_float($value))return ($value===(float)(int)$value);
    if(!is_string($value))return false;
    return !!preg_match('/^(0|\-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/',$value);
}
```

`is_string()` check is required in both, as otherwise first function gives false positives, and second produces warnings. Function's purpose is to *validate*, possible type-juggling is done elsewhere.

Some test-results:

```
$values = array(
    '-0',
    -0,
    0,
    123,
    -123,
    '123',
    '-123',
    '0123',
    '123 ',
    '0',
    '000',
    '+123',
    '1.23',
    1.23,
    '123e4',
    '0x123',
    'potato',
    'EEBD',
    true,
    false,
    null,
    '10000000000000000000',
    10000000000000000000
);

PHP version: 5.4.30
string(2) "-0" = bool(false) bool(false)
int(0) = bool(true) bool(true)
int(0) = bool(true) bool(true)
int(123) = bool(true) bool(true)
int(-123) = bool(true) bool(true)
string(3) "123" = bool(true) bool(true)
string(4) "-123" = bool(true) bool(true)
string(4) "0123" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(4) "123 " = bool(false) bool(false)
string(1) "0" = bool(true) bool(true)
string(3) "000" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(4) "+123" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(4) "1.23" = bool(false) bool(false)
float(1.23) = bool(false) bool(false)
float(2) = bool(true) bool(true)
string(5) "123e4" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(5) "0x123" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(6) "potato" = bool(false) bool(false)
string(4) "EEBD" = bool(false) bool(false)
bool(true) = bool(false) bool(false)
bool(false) = bool(false) bool(false)
NULL = bool(false) bool(false)
string(20) "10000000000000000000" = bool(false) bool(true)
float(1.0E+19) = bool(false) bool(false)
```

(Source for var-list (nearly as is) and idea for the regex: http://wisercoder.com/check-for-integer-in-php/)

[EDIT]
`preg_match`-based function wont work, because it either allows overflowing integers (current) or has to disallow possible integers.

Comment: This question might be better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: Maybe. My "mistake" was that I combined both original question and code I wrote after getting an idea after writing the question.

Comment: "For example, filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT passes "123 " (notice space at the end)." That's because PHP itself considers "123 " a valid number.